# Как передать данные (изображение)

Tags: php, .net, exec, execute

Здравствуйте, в общем такая ситуация: нужно, чтобы php вызывал программу и .net программа возвращала* изображение, чтобы потом php вывела её на web странице.

*Это программа загружает pdf файл и ищёт по определённому ключевому слову страницу, которую затем переводит в png... и дальше как png передать php я не знаю.

Comment: если приложение консольное или какое то такое, то пусть просто отдает данные на стандартный вывод. А php может ее запустить, получить вывод. Самое просто с помощью system(), но не факт что двоичный вывод нормально пройдет. тогда чем то вроде popen(). С другой стороны .net приложение может быть простейшим web-сервером и постоянно быть запущенным. тогда php код куда то кладет php, что бы программа могла найти, отдает клиенту `<img src="server:port/....">`  и .net уже как web-приложение получает из url некий код по которому понимает какую pdf взять и отдает png  клиенту (можно вообще без php)

Comment: Можно тут чуть чуть по подробнее "тогда php код куда то кладет php, что бы программа могла найти, отдает клиенту "?

Comment: я имел ввиду "куда то кладет pdf". Я так понял она его от клиента получает ? пусть кладет под каким то сгенерированным именем в temp. А .net из запроса клиента получает некую информацию на основании которой вычисляет имя файла. ну и тогда еще надо будет предусмотреть периодическую чистку temp от не нужных файлов

Comment: А не, у меня проще ситуация, у меня одна книжка (типа справочника), по которой идёт поиск и всё, ни кто не чего не грузит

Comment: Тогда заранее переведите всю pdf постранично в png и храните их готовые. А что касается слов ... Я бы так же обработал PDF один раз, собрал список всех встречающихся слов и номеров страниц (или может и более точные координаты) и сохранил бы это в БД. После чего  при обращении пользователя вообще бы больше не обращался к .net приложению, а искал бы в БД и выдавал нужные PNG

Comment: @Mike хорошая идея, так и сделаю, спасибо. Напишите это ответом

Comment: но он не будет соответствовать тому, что спрашивается в изначальном вопросе. ни о какой передаче данных между .net и php там уже не будет ни слова ...

Comment: @Mike ну тогда удалить тему?